# B-spline of 3 grade (non-uniform and non-fractal) in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, bspline

I have a problem with modifying my code based on Bézier curve (which works) to B-spline.
This is how it draws:

[image: Text]

Basic formula:
[image: Text]

```cpp
void MainWindow::rysujKrzywa(int koniec){
    double x, y;
    tm = m - 3;
    for( double t = 0; t <= m-2; t += 0.01){
        x = ((((-1 * pow(t-tm,3)) + (3 * pow(t-tm,2)) - (3 * (t-tm)) + 1) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 2]) +
                ((((3 * pow(t-tm,3)) - (6* pow(t-tm,2)) + 4) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 4]) +
                ((((-3 * pow(t-tm,3)) +(3 * pow(t-tm,2)) + 3*(t-tm) +1) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 6]) +
                (((pow(t-tm,3))/6) * punkty[koniec - 8]);
        y = ((((-1 * pow(t-tm,3)) + (3 * pow(t-tm,2)) - (3 * (t-tm)) + 1) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 1]) +
                ((((3 * pow(t-tm,3)) - (6* pow(t-tm,2)) + 4) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 3]) +
                ((((-3 * pow(t-tm,3)) +(3 * pow(t-tm,2)) + 3*(t-tm) +1) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 5]) +
                (((pow(t-tm,3))/6) * punkty[koniec - 7]);
        drawPixel( int(x), int(y), 255, 0, 0);
    }
    update();
}
```

```
a small dictionary:
punkty - saved points
koniec - end
```

Full code at the repository: https://gitlab.com/Sempron/b-spline

Comment: no wonder you made a mistake in this monster expressions. Better slip them up in smaller parts, test them individually, put them back together, profit

Comment: I agree with @idclev463035818. Some parts of this expression are clearly repeated and should be given a clear name. Just replacing `t-tm` with something descriptive would help.

Comment: "slip" ?!? I meant "split" of course. And "monster" wasnt meant as offense, but seriously for me those lines are far too complicated, if I wrote them I would make more than one mistake for sure

Comment: m describes a segment - we start with 3 and we increment it with every segment.
tm = m - 3, cause we start with 0

Comment: @Sempron You do the same calculations many times. Break each one out and give it a name. Sometimes that's all one needs to find the error. What _is_ `t-tm`? Name it properly and put that in the expression. Then take the next etc.

Comment: One suggestion: Instead of providing a dictionary (which is better than nothing) - translate the code _before_ posting it so that no dictionary is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If code looks complicated then quite likely it really is too complicated.

Lets concentrate on this part:

```
x = ((((-1 * pow(t-tm,3)) + (3 * pow(t-tm,2)) - (3 * (t-tm)) + 1) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 2]) +
            ((((3 * pow(t-tm,3)) - (6* pow(t-tm,2)) + 4) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 4]) +
            ((((-3 * pow(t-tm,3)) +(3 * pow(t-tm,2)) + 3*(t-tm) +1) / 6) * punkty[koniec - 6]) +
            (((pow(t-tm,3))/6) * punkty[koniec - 8]);
```

Then you can introduce a

```
auto temp = t-tm;
```

Next, in the formula you have four different terms. I do not see them in your code. Make them explicit

```
auto x_term1 = - pow(temp,3) + (3 * pow(temp,2)) - (3 * temp + 1);    
x_term1 *= punkty[koniec - 2] / 6;
auto x_term2 = ...
...
x = x_term1 + x_term2 + x_term3 + x_term4;
```

It is likely that while refactoring code to be readable you will already fix the problem. If not use pen and paper (or similar) to get example output for example input for each individual term (you should do this in any case so you can test your code without inspecting the image). Then use a debugger to see which term is off.

PS: Better dont use `pow` to square numbers. `pow` is for floating point exponents which is more costly than what you need here. I just didnt want to change your actual calculations.